# Auto rotation when iPhone rotate

Tags: iphone, automation

I am new in iPhone development... now i developed one Test application.in it 4 view is there..

my problem is that..when i rotate my simulator first 2 view will rotate automatically( landsacpe and Portrate  mode).. but 3 and 4 not rotating . that time i got one exception.. that is

//----------------------------------------------------

GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i386-apple-darwin".warning: Unable to read symbols for "/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit" (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "UIKit" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics" (file not found).

//----------------------------------------------------

in control class i override the "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation " the YES retrun..

i used i Phone sdk is 2.2 version

pls help me ... if u want more details inform me.. this is urget..

thnx and regards.. by raju

Answer (score 0):

Did you override the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in ALL your view controllers?

The part you posted from the exception means nothing, we'd need to see the sack trace.  I'm not sure it's really related to the rotation issue though.

Comment: thnks for reply .. if you have any sample code .. let me give it ? pls

Answer (score 0):

The trace you have in your question are not the exception, They are just harmless warnings that are unrelated to your problem.

Where is the exception?

Comment: i thought it was exception... when it coming the application will stuck. then how can apply the auto rotation property in all view in my application. in my application 5 view is there.. i can manage first two.. one i load in main window when start up.. another one i load using "initwithnib:bundle"method.. when i tried to load IIIrd one. it will load correctly but when we rotate the phone(left or right, landsacpe or protrate) this warnings come and application will stuck... this is my proble.. pls help me...

Comment: Getting stuck is different than exception. Can you suspend your process in gdb to know where the process is stuck?